# Is it Possible to trigger request when request received by MockService (Onrequest Script)

Tags: rest, groovy, mocking, soapui

I'm trying to automatically trigger a REST request with a groovy script "OnRequest Script"
when my mockservice receives a request.

From "OnRequest Script" I have access to "log, context, mockRequest and mockRunner" variables.

How can I run a testStep or a TestCase from my mockService? Is it possible?

Can I create a new REST request in my mockService and send it?

Comment: Remember: "There are no stupid questions"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create REST request using HTTPBuilder in groovy script. 
Examples: [get request](http://groovy.codehaus.org/modules/http-builder/doc/get.html), [post request](http://groovy.codehaus.org/modules/http-builder/doc/post.html)

Or you can use [RESTClient](http://groovy.codehaus.org/modules/http-builder/doc/rest.html) - it is an extension of HTTPBuilder

Comment: Thanks @artem-izyumov.

but i have an error in "error log":

unable to resole class groovyx.net.http.HTTPBuilder @ line 3, column 1. import groovyx.net.http.HTTPBuilder ;

so, how can i resolve it ?

Comment: You need to download jar file with HTTPBuilder (for example -http://snapshots.repository.codehaus.org/org/codehaus/groovy/modules/http-builder/http-builder/0.6-SNAPSHOT/http-builder-0.6-20121009.052743-1.jar) and put it to soap ui classpath (in your soap ui installation folder - directory bin/ext) so it would be visible for groovy scripts

Comment: Thank you; 
Sorry, but i have another problem i don't understand:
I copied jar file and did unzip in directory bin/ext;
but when it arrives to create RESTClient object, it shows:
"java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError Could not initialize class groovyx.net.http.ParserRegistry"
but ParserRegistry.class exists in bin/ext repertory.
Do you have any idea?
thank you

Comment: You don't need to unzip jar file, just put it to bin/ext folder

Comment: I did both cases, and i had the same problem

Comment: it crash in the first line:
`def reqPut = new RESTClient(); try { reqPut.setUri('http://localhost:8182/chat/v1/tel:+33612345789/oneToOne/tel:+33609875432/d48267e1-2bfd-480e-ac48-2cfb62aa2019/messages/6ab1aedc00b343f1a8b1e74bcd07b3' )
  reqPut.setContentType( "application/xml" )
  reqPut.put( path : '/status', body : "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?><chat:messageStatusReport xmlns:chat=\"urn:oma:xml:rest:netapi:chat:1\"><status>Delivered</status></chat:messageStatusReport>", requestContentType : "application/xml")
} catch ( ex ) {log.info( " response status: " + ex.response.status)}`

Comment: Gotcha. http-builder has dependencies, that also should be in bin/ext. Download  http://repository.codehaus.org/org/codehaus/groovy/modules/http-builder/http-builder/0.6/http-builder-0.6-all.zip , unzip and add jars from dependencies folder to bin/ext. With your code I add only xml-resolver.jar addytionally and it works.